# Keyboard-trackpad combos for Mac, where the trackpad lies underneath the keyboard.

Tags: keyboard, trackpad

I am currently looking for a keyboard-trackpad combo for the Mac where the trackpad lies underneath beneath the keyboard (i.e. just like they would be on a Macbook; in fact the reason why I'm looking for this is to make it easier to use a desktop).

As of right now, the only system that I know of that does this is the [BulletTrain Express](http://www.bullettrain.com/express.html). A few other keyboard-trackpad combinations exist, though in most cases the trackpad is small and does not support multitouch gestures.

I'm wondering if anyone knows an alternative to the BulletTrain Express? Alternatively (possibly another question), would it be possible to buy an [old Macbook Pro body](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B7954W2) and use that as a with some modifications?

Comment: I was thinking the exact same thing !

Comment: @thinkanotherone I ended up going with the BulletTrain Express. It's a little expensive but it works well... Cheaper used models are available on eBay.

Comment: @BerkU so after a while using BulletTrain Express, what do you think? Does it worth the expensive price tag?

Comment: @HieuRocker I'm pretty satisfied with it. The latest version for the Magic Trackpad/Keyboard 2 is a well designed product, and I haven't had any issues. The $129 price tag *is* a little ridiculous given that it's really just a piece of plastic... but I just decided to bite the bullet since I couldn't find any alternative.

Comment: @BerkU. I been using it since May 2018 and I love it too